# Bash: find function in files with the same content

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation, devops

I'm trying to solve some problem that would behave as follow
Let's quote situation
In the directory, I have few scripts with some content (it doesn't matter what it's doing)

- example1.sh
- example2.sh
- example3.sh
- ...etc

Altogether there are 50 scripts
Some of these scripts contain the same function, for example

```
function foo1
{
    echo "Hello"
}
```

and in some scripts function can be named the same but has other content or modified, for example

```
function foo1
{
    echo "$PWD"
}
```

or

```
function foo1
{
    echo "Hello"
    ls -la
}
```

I have to find the same function with the same name and the same content in these scripts
For example,
foo1 the same or modified content in example1.sh and example2.sh -> what I want
foo1 other content in example1.sh and example3.sh -> not interested

My question is what is the best idea to solve this problem? What do you think?
My idea was to sort content from all scripts and grep names of repeated functions. I managed to do that but still, it's not what I want because I have to check every file with this function and check its content... and it's a pain in the neck because for some functions there are 10 scripts...

I was wondering about extracting content from repeated functions but I don't know how to do it, what do you think? Or maybe you have some other suggestions?

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Comment: by 'same content' I'm assuming you mean the same set of commands but not necessarily the same formatting (eg, could have different number of lines, spaces vs tabs, 2 spaces vs 1 space between text, braces on their own lines vs end of lines containing text, etc) in which case you'll need some sort of parser that can look past the formatting issues and extract just the bare bones basic content

Comment: Are you scripts safely `source`able, or can they be modified to be so? Using `declare -f` may be an option in that case.

Comment: Note that there are several different ways to declare a function, and those involving the `function` keyword are neither the most common nor the best (the POSIX-standardized `foo1() {` approach is more portable, whereas `function` is only available in shells -- like bash -- with backwards compatibility to ksh).

Comment: ...in general, I would recommend that folks write code that doesn't _require_ the kind of technique requested here. Keep your functions in separate files (`.bash`, not `.sh`, the `function` keyword isn't specified in POSIX sh so when you name a shell library with bash/ksh-only syntax with `.sh` you risk someone trying to source its contents into ash or dash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a message digest of the content of each function and use it as a key in an associative array. Add files that contain the same function digest to find duplicates.

You may want to normalize space in the function content and tweak the regex address range.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# the 1st argument is the function name
func_name="$1"
func_pattern="^function $func_name[[:blank:]]*$"
shift
declare -A dupe_groups

while read -r func_dgst file; do # collect results in an associative array
    dupe_groups[$func_dgst]+="$file "
done < <( # the remaining arguments are scripts
    for f in "${@}"; do
        if grep --quiet "$func_pattern" "$f"; then
            dgst=$( # use an address range in sed to print function contents
                sed -n "/$func_pattern/,/^}/p" "$f" | \
                # pipe to openssl to create a message digest
                openssl dgst -sha1 )
            echo "$dgst $f"
        fi
    done )

# print the results
for key in "${!dupe_groups[@]}"; do
    echo "$key ${dupe_groups[$key]}"
done
```

I tested with your example{1..3}.sh files added the following example4.sh for a duplicate function.

example4.sh

```
function foo1
{
    echo "Hello"
    ls -la
}

function another
{
    echo "there"
}
```

To run

```sh
./group-func.sh foo1 example1.sh example2.sh example3.sh example4.sh
```

Results

```
155853f813e944a7fcc5ae73ee2d959e300d217a example1.sh 
7848af9b8b9d48c5cb643f34b3e5ca26cb5bfbdd example2.sh 
4771de27523a765bb0dbf070691ea1cbae841375 example3.sh example4.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

> what is the best idea to solve this problem?

Write a shell language tokenizer and implement syntax parsing enough to extract function definitions from a file. Sources of shell implementations will be an inspiration. Then build a database of file->function+body and list all files with same function+body.

For simple enough functions, an `awk` or `perl` or `python` script would be enough to cover most cases. But the best would be full shell language tokenizer.

Do not use `function name {`. Instead use `name() {`. See [bash obsolete and deprecated syntax](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

---

With the following files:

```
# file1.sh
function foo1
{
    echo "Hello"
}


# file2.sh
function foo1
{
    echo "Hello"
}

# file3.sh
function foo1
{
    echo "$PWD"
}


# file4.sh
function foo1
{
    echo "$PWD"
}
```

The following script:

```
printf "%s\n" *.sh |
while IFS= read -r file; do
     sed -zE '
           s/(function[[:space:]]+([[:print:]]+)[[:space:]]*\{|(function[[:space:]]+)?([[:print:]]+)[[:space:]]*\([[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*\{)([^}]*)}/\x01\2\4\n\5\x02/g;
           /\x01/!d;
           s/[^\x01\x02]*\x01([^\x01\x02]*)\x02[^\x01\x02]*/\1\n\x00/g
        ' "$file" |
     sed -z 's~^~'"$file"'\x01~';
done |
awk -v RS='\0' -v FS='\1' '
        {cnt[$2]++; a[$2]=a[$2]" "$1}
        END{ for (i in cnt) if (cnt[i] > 1) print a[i], i }
'
```

outputs:

```
 file1.sh file2.sh foo1

    echo "Hello"


 file3.sh file4.sh foo1

    echo "$PWD"
```

Indicating there is the same function `foo1` in `file1.sh` and `file2.sh` and the same function `foo1` in `file3.sh` and `file4.sh`.

Also note that a script can and do:

```
if condition; then
   func() { echo something; }
else
   func() { echo something else; }
fi
```

A real tokenizer will have to also take that into account.